# on prometheus how to pull a metric based on a specific label

Tags: prometheus

Team,

I formed a query and also have result but am not able to go further by filtering it by a label.

I want to further filter my result based on mountpoint / and /raid.. how can i?
query

```
(kube_pod_info{namespace="monitoring",node=~"(team|wkr).*"}
* 
on(pod) group_right(node) 
(
max by(instance, namespace, pod, device, mountpoint) (
(
  node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype=~"ext[234]|btrfs|xfs|zfs"} 
  - 
  node_filesystem_avail_bytes{fstype=~"ext[234]|btrfs|xfs|zfs"}
) 
/ 
node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype=~"ext[234]|btrfs|xfs|zfs"}
)
))
```

output

```
{device="/dev/sdb1",instance="101.1.1.1:1401",mountpoint="/raid",namespace="monitoring",node="team11",pod="prometheus-node-exporter-dcp-173-4l2dr"} 
{device="/dev/sdb1",instance="101.1.1.1:1401",mountpoint="/",namespace="monitoring",node="team11",pod="prometheus-node-exporter-dcp-173-4l2dr"}
```

The work around am using is below

````
yes want to see based on either of those two [/ or /raid] like using grep on results obtained..but i figure out a work around by setting them in expression itself like below

```node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype=~"ext[234]|btrfs|xfs|zfs", mountpoint="/raid"`
````

so full expression would be

```
(kube_pod_info{namespace="monitoring",node=~"(team|wkr).*"}
* 
on(pod) group_right(node) 
(
max by(instance, namespace, pod, device, mountpoint) (
(
  node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype=~"ext[234]|btrfs|xfs|zfs",mountpoint="/raid"} 
  - 
  node_filesystem_avail_bytes{fstype=~"ext[234]|btrfs|xfs|zfs",mountpoint="/raid"}
) 
/ 
node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype=~"ext[234]|btrfs|xfs|zfs",mountpoint="/raid"}
)
))
```

Comment: what do you mean by "filter my result based on mountpoint / and /raid" do you only want to see results from these two mountpoints?

Comment: yes want to see based on either of those like using grep on results obtained..but i figure out a work around by setting them in expression itself like below
`node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype=~"ext[234]|btrfs|xfs|zfs", mountpoint="/raid"`

Comment: I added it to my answer but need to know if there is a way to get the work around using `prom-ql` equivalent to `grep`